# Order by rows of different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have "user_likes" table with `id(int(10) key), user_id(varchar(15)), post_id(varchar(15))` and "user_post" table with `post_id(int(15) key), user_id(varchar(15)), post_txt(text)`

I now order the posts by id:

```
$que_posts = mysql_query("select * from user_post order by user_id DESC");
```

I want to order it by amount of likes to each post(i.e. posts with more likes will be first).

The problem is that the LIKES are in different table. How can I do it?

Edit- I using sef4eg's answer(with changes) I could fix it:

```
"SELECT user_post.*, COUNT(user_likes.post_id) AS like_count
                            FROM user_post LEFT JOIN user_likes 
                            ON user_post.post_id = user_likes.post_id
                            GROUP BY user_post.post_id
                            ORDER BY like_count desc;";
```

Comment: Use JOINS  maybe ?

Comment: U can try join... MYSQL_* is deprecated and closed in Php 7... Use mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: Also as a suggestion, you should not have user_id for user_likes table, as post_id itself acts like foreign key

Comment: @AbhilashRVankayala I think the user_id in user_posts identifies the poster and the user_id in user_likes identifies the liker.

Answer (score 1):

Now you have `like_count` in your select so you display it if you need to

```
SELECT user_post.*, COUNT(user_likes.id) as like_count
FROM user_post 
LEFT JOIN user_likes
ON user_likes.user_id = user_post.user_id AND user_likes.post_id = user_post.post_id
GROUP BY user_post.post_id
ORDER BY like_count DESC
```

Comment: It does show me posts but in id order and not by likes

Comment: I think it's a data problem, sql query definitely should sort records by number of like records not id